# Scanning till EOF in python

Tags: python

One way I know how to do it is

```
while 1:
   try:
       n=int(raw_input())
   except:
       break
```

Any other way shorter than this ?

By shorter than this I mean simply consumes lesser number of characters.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The indentation is broken, and if it weren't, it'd still keep looping after input ends.

Comment: Do you want to do anything with the input or just wait for the EOF?

Comment: @user2357112   why? if it does not receive any input it would raise a error, and so will break the while loop

Comment: @IskarJarak i need the in-between contents as well.

Comment: Oh, wait, there's a `break` there. I thought that was a `pass`. This'll read until it can't turn the input into an integer, which may or may not be when the input ends.

Comment: What do you mean "consumes lesser number of characters"? By definition, any working answer to your question will consume all characters in stdin until EOF, so anything that consumes a lesser number is broken.

Comment: @Ninja420 Then there are some adequate answers now.

Comment: @abarnert i wanted the length of code to be shorter than that.

Answer (score 3):

For the following code, the `read()` call will block until EOF is encountered:

```
import sys
sys.stdin.read()
```

Or to do this a line at a time to consume less memory:

```
import sys
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    pass
```

Comment: Why not just `for line in sys.stdin: pass`? (There are of course downsides to that, but if all you want to do is consume all of stdin, none of them matter.)

Comment: I had noticed that when using `for line in sys.stdin: pass` I would need to Ctrl-D twice for the script to exit, possibly due to some buffering.  Not sure if that was something about my setup or a difference between how the two pieces of code work though.

Comment: Yes, it can have some problems with interactive tty use on some platforms, but it still fits the OP's requirement, and without knowing anything about his actual use case, I'd still suggest it with caveats. For actual interactive use, you might want to stick with `raw_input` anyway, so it works properly in IDEs that replace `raw_input`. (For a non-trivial script, you could write a simple iterate-until-EOFError wrapper, and then just use that in a one-liner. For a trivial script, it's hard to beat the original version, except of course to use `True` instead of `1` and `except EOFError`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

sys.stdin.read()  # Reads all input.
```